# Trigonometry word problem (involving wires)

Tags: trigonometry, physics

A guy wire $78$ feet long runs from the top of a pole $56$ feet high to the ground and pulls on the pole with a force of $290$ pounds. What is the horizontal Pull on the top of the poll?

---

I am not sure how do this problem. I tried to draw a triangle and one side is $56$ and the hypotenuse is $78$, but I am not sure what to do.

Comment: you have your picture.  Now imagine a somebody pulling on the end of that wire.  That force is going to be transmitted up the wire to the top of the pole.  And that force will have a horizontal component and a vertical component.  Any idea by what ratio that force will be spread between horizontal and vertical?

Comment: If the angle between the pole and the wire would be 90°, all the force will be horizontal, right? On the other side, the horizontal power would be 0, if the angle is 0°. I have no idea about the _physical_ calculation, but it sounds like $sin$. So the horizontal power might be $sin(\alpha)*290$.

Comment: The resultant force is 290  pounds I think or is the vertical force I am not sure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the force diagram:

[image: force_diagram]

Observe that the horizontal component of the force is $\boldsymbol{F}_h = \boldsymbol{F}\cos\theta$, where $\boldsymbol{F} = 2900~\text{lb}$ in the indicated direction.  Also, observe that $$\theta = \arcsin\left(\frac{56~\text{ft}}{78~\text{ft}}\right)$$

Answer (score 5):

So, force is a vector and any force vector can be visualized in the Cartesian coordinate plane and decompose this vector into its components (horizontal, vertical, etc.).

Always drawing a diagram (Force diagram) in these word problems is very helpful. So, draw a right triangle that best depicts the scenario.

We want to find the angles of this triangle that will help us answer this question. What is this angle? Let's say we want to find the angle $(\theta)$ between the height $(56)$ and the hypotenuse $(78)$. $\cos(\theta)=56/78$

Now, we have that the person is pulling the wire so that the force on the wire is along the wire. Given the $\theta$ that we defined, the magnitude of the vertical component of the force is the magnitude of the resultant force $\cdot \cos(\theta)$ and the horizontal component of the force is the magnitude of the resultant force $\cdot\sin(\theta)$.

I will leave the specific calculations up to you. Cheers,